# What is "overkill"?

Tags: terminology

Programmers often [wonder if the use of a certain library or programming style is overkill](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3aquestion%20overkill).  They also often [claim that this is the case](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3aanswer%20overkill) (and they are [often believed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3aanswer%20isaccepted%3ayes%20overkill)).

What does "overkill" mean in the context of programming?

Comment: this is a question for programmers.stackexchange.com not stackoverflow

Comment: It has the same meaning as in every other context: More than what is needed. Also, this questions seems off-topic for SO imho.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about linguistics, not a programming problem.

Answer (score 6):

"overkill" is typically used to mean deploying overly flexible and/or over-engineered solutions to solve what is ostensibly a simple and highly localized problem. The canonical example is [FizzBuzz Enterprise Edition](https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition).

Answer (score 3):

The term "Overkill" literarilly (if there was ever a literal use of it) refers to the action of killing something or someone, with more resources than necessary. Something like shooting a deer 50 times to make sure it dies.

In programming it applies for the same principle: making use of more resources than necessary or to find an overly complex solution to a simple problem.

Some simple examples are

```
for i=1 to 100
   x[i]=2^z[i];
   y=x;    
end
```

Where copying the entire array `x` in every iteration step achieves the desired result but you could also copy it elementwise `y[i]=x[i]` saving you some 900 operations and is thus an overkill.

Using the OpenCV library to threshold an image is definetley possible but uses many more resources than strictly necessary and is an exagerated example of an overkill.

Comment: I don't think the simple example you're providing is actually overkill. I think it might just be bad code.

Comment: `x * 3` and `x[i] * 3` will probably produce different results. Maybe the programmer needs `x * 3` instead of `x[i] * 3`. It's a bad example for overkill, imo.

Comment: I just noticed so (4 years later!). You are completely right! It should be correct now.